# Backup/restore check data is the same SQL Server

Tags: backup, restore

I'm a trainee SQL DBA. I'm using SSMS 2008r2. 
I've backed up a database and restored this as a new database on a new instance. 
I want to check to see if the data is the same on both databases. Is there a way I can do this without running select commands on both databases and comparing?

Thanks. 
Ryan.

Comment: Yes there might be some tool to compare, I am not aware about such tools. But rest assured if you have restored database successfully all data present in SQL Server during backup would be there in destination database.

Comment: RedGate's SQL COMPARE, DBComparer  just google database compare and you will see a lot of products

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I really appreciate it, just a shame business don't allow 3rd party software on their systems.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Data Tools offers a Data/Schema comparison option. You need to install it, previous download of it, and then do the comparison.

More information on how to compare in [How to: Compare and Synchronize the Data of Two Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn266028(v=vs.103).aspx).

To download the free tool, please visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx.